# Http is not assignable to parameter of type HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I copied an ionic app from a friend. I tried running ionic serve but i get this error in the image below. Ionic Cordova build android also gives errors. [image]

here is my ionic info

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 2.3.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v6.12.0
npm               : 3.10.10 
OS                : Linux 4.13
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: have you Added HttpClientModule in your Module file??

Comment: @abhishekgangwar, thanks, that helped to resolve the issue